# x86_64 memory reorder

Tags: concurrency, x86-64, memory-model

on x86_64 architecture, whether the following code will always hold:

A=1;B=1;

Thread1 : store A=2; store B=3;
Thread2 : load B==3; load A==2

is there any posibilities that B==3 but A==1  ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 8.2.3 of Volumes 3A and 3B of the Intel architecture manual go into great depth on this subject, however, for your case (`8.2.3.7 Stores Are Seen in a Consistent Order by Other Processors`), there is strict ordering, which means writes are observed in the order in which they are made, making it impossible for `B` to read the updated value while `A` still has the old value.

It should be noted that its generally a good idea to provide explicit barriers in cases like this by using the various memory fencing instructions available, `SFENCE`,`LFENCE` & `MFENCE` via `_mm_sfence`, `_mm_lfence` & `_mm_mfence`. under x64 you also have the option of `__faststorefence`(MSVC only).

Comment: previously I also readed chapter 8.2.3 of the intel architecture, the different part is the read/write sequence is the same in two thread. what I confused is : if the memory system  of server that thread 2 running at processes invalidate queue out of order, then the unexpected case will happen?

Comment: @foxmailed: thats where `8.2.3.2 Neither Loads Nor Stores Are Reordered with Like Operations` comes in, its example describes your scenario exactly: `The disallowed return values could be exhibited only if processor 0’s two stores are
reordered (with the two loads occurring between them) or if processor 1’s two loads
are reordered (with the two stores occurring between them).` In this case you need to ensure total order by using an atomic or a memory barrier as I mentioned.